# BroadcastReceiver in Singleton class not receiving intents

Tags: android, android-intent, singleton, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I have a Broadcast receiver in a singleton class that's not receiving Broadcast intents.

The singleton is initialized with a context (i.e. getInstance(context)).

I call getContext().sendBroadcast(intent); but the BroadcastReceiver doesn't get anything.  I've confirmed the intent filters are matching.

The way I register the receiver is in my singleton constructor like so

```
private class Singleton(Context context) {
    context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, INTENT_FILTER);
....

private onDestroy(Context context) {
    context.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
....
```

What's going on!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I figured out what I did wrong.  The Singleton is being created by activity and hence the context being passed in is an **Activity Context.**  Hence I needed to update my constructor to this:

```
private class Singleton(Context context) {
    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, INTENT_FILTER);
```

Not sure why this makes a difference.  My guess is that the activity context is destroyed and hence the BroadcastReceiver with it?  Additional insight is welcome!